# Insert table data with column datatype varchar2 to a table with column datatype as number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

In oracle DB I have a table TABLE1 with column datatype defined as VARCHAR2(50). I have another table TABLE2 with column datatype defined as a NUMBER. The no of rows present in the TABLE1 is around 23k and they all seems to be number. But when I try the insert command I get the below error.

```
    Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

This clearly means that there are few rows that are not numbers. But I am not able to identify those no numeric cases. How do I identify the non numeric rows.

P.S:
Oracle database version : 9.2.0.8.0

And yes I know its ancient.

Comment: Do they 'seem to be' plain integers, or do they have group and/or decimal separators? If they have separators, do your session NLS settings match those (specifically NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS)?

Comment: maybe `select col  from table1 where translate(col,'.0123456789',' ') is not null;`  I think translate was in 9

Comment: They are plain integers and no decimal points in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the PL SQL block used to identify the discrepancy cases. The special character in my case was double quotes. There were few cases with issue so printing the output was feasible. If there are more number of discrepancy cases then capturing the error msg in a table column will be helpful.

```
declare
cursor cur is
select * from TABLE1 ;           ----- cursor to loop through cases individually
begin
for rec in cur 
loop 
begin
insert into table2 (column1)
select to_number(column1)
from table1
where
column1=rec.column1 ;
exception when others
then
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('error for '||rec.column1||' '||substr(sqlerrm,0,150)); --- error msg with discrepancy case
end;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: But what is the use of this. This doent help in solving your question

Comment: With the block I was able to identify the non numeric cases .`select to_number(column1)
from table1
where
column1=rec.column1 ;` will throw an exception when row is non numeric. If its a number then the row gets inserted in the table `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing numbers in a string?  That is the fundamental problem.

You can avoid the rows using a `where` clause:

```
insert into table2( . . .)
    select . . .
    from table1 t1
    where regexp_like(numbercol, '^[0-9]+$')
```

This assumes that "number" means "non-negative integer".  Obviously the pattern can be generalized for other ranges and/or numeric formats.

You can just identify the non-numeric rows by running a similar `select`:

```
    select . . .
    from table1 t1
    where not regexp_like(numbercol, '^[0-9]+$')
```

Comment: The base table from which TABLE1 was created has column declared as varchar2 datatype. Hence its TABLE1 has varchar2.
Thank you for the answer. But I am on Oracle 9i I don't have regular expression function.